# Razorpay is not redirecting to checkout page

Tags: ios, swift, swift5, razorpay

I am using,

- Xcode - 13.1
- Swift language version - swift 5
- RazorPay framework version - 1.1.2 (pod 'razorpay-pod', '~>1.1.2')

My problem is when I am calling this,

`razorpay.open(options)`

after using payment method.... It gives me an unexpected error (code - 1) with

```
/Users/ramprasad.a/Documents/RamprasadA/project/razorpay-ios/RazorpayIOS/CheckoutOtpelf/Classes/RazorpayCheckoutVC.swift deinitialized
```

[image: /Users/ramprasad.a/Documents/RamprasadA/project/razorpay-ios/RazorpayIOS/CheckoutOtpelf/Classes/RazorpayCheckoutVC.swift deinitialized]

Comment: Does this help: https://github.com/razorpay/razorpay-pod/issues/82 ?

Comment: I'm getting this error only when I click success and failure button.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using navigation controller to push view controller use:

`razorpay?.open(options, displayController: self)`

else if the view controller is presented:

`razorpay?.open(options, displayController: self)`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).